# Calculating error of linear regression coefficient, given errors of y

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am processing my lab measurements related to measuring the speed of sound. To put my goal simply, I have a series of measurements `y(x)` as follows:

```
x       y
0       0
1     212
2     426
3     640
4     858
5    1074
6    1290
7    1506
8    1722
9    1939
```

And also I know the measurements of `y` may be off by 2. So, for example, with `x = 1`, `y` could be anywhere from 210 to 214. I wanna know how much impact this error has on the coefficients of linear regression.

I was using `sklearn` `LinearRegression` and with `fit_intercept=False` parameter the task wasn't so hard. I just needed to calculate the coefficient for series `y - 2` and `y + 2` and get the difference. But then I have to do a similar task without `fit_intercept=False` (so `y` is not 0 when `x` is 0).

So I am wondering are there any officially implemented ways to achieve my goal? Not necessarily in `sklearn`.

Comment: "I just needed to calculate coefficient for series y - 2 and y + 2" - that isn't true: if you add or subtract a constant from all y values then you will get exactly the same SLOPE.

Comment: @lastchance yes, so the OP is asking the max an min slopes, so he can get an error for the slope. The min slope happens when the first readings have a +2 error and the last readings have a -2 error. But to get the exact minimum slope it's not clear where the transition from -2 to +2 errors happen.  You don't have much datapoints, so you could try sliding the change point and see where it gets the minimum slope. Same for max slope

Comment: @lastchance As I stated in the question, first I was using `fit_intercept=False` configuration, so it does produce min and max slope for this particular situation. Now I am asking how to solve the general case.

Comment: @Alexander Vronksky - I have written out an answer for the cases with and without fitting the intercept as 0.

Comment: @Elerium, you can make the "transition" between positive and negative errors at x=x_mean (if the intercept is to be calculated) and at x=0 (if the intercept is forced to be the origin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope coefficient `m` in `y = mx + c` is found below. (I suspect that you only need the slope to get the speed of sound from your data.)

**(Case 1)** If non-zero intercept c is allowed then the slope is:

[image]

and the denominator is positive. (It is N times the variance of x).

To get the MAXIMUM slope you want to maximize:

[image]

So, *take the greatest possible value of `y` if `x` is greater than `x_mean` and the smallest value of `y` if `x` is less than x_mean*.

To get the MINIMUM slope then minimize the numerator by doing the reverse.

**(Case 2)** If the intercept `c` is forced to be zero (the line has to go through the origin) then the slope is:

[image]

Since the `x` values are fixed then *maximize the slope by taking the largest possible value of `y` where `x` is positive and the smallest possible value when `x` is negative*. Again, do the reverse to get the minimum slope.

Comment: Thank you, this works wonderfully. And what do you think about generalizing this approach for multivariable regression?

Comment: It was OK for just y against x as m is essentially linear in the y values and given explicitly. For multivariate regression ... not sure, as the coefficients would need solving for by a linear system. Also one independent variable (x1) might be greater than the mean but another (x2) less than the mean ... so it is not clear what you would do to the dependent variable y.

Answer (score 1):

This is an empirical approach which runs a noise impact study with uniform-noise trials on the original data.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#
# Data
#
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'y': [0, 212, 426, 640, 858, 1074, 1290, 1506, 1722, 1939]
})

#
# Get parameter estimates from original data + model
#
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

#Get slope/intercept of the data
ref_model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(data[['x']], data[['y']])
ref_slope = ref_model.coef_[0]
ref_intercept = ref_model.intercept_

#
# Noise the data and record the estimated parameters
#

#Set the noise trial parameters
noise_amplitude = 2
num_noise_trials = 1000

trial_slopes = []
trial_intercepts = []
for trial in range(num_noise_trials):
    y_noised = data.y + rng.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=len(data)) * noise_amplitude
    
    lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(data[['x']], y_noised)
    trial_slopes.append(lr.coef_[0])
    trial_intercepts.append(lr.intercept_)

#
# Plot, comparing non-noised vs noised estimates.
# Include some trial stats.
#
f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(7, 5), sharex=True, layout='tight')
ax = axs[0]
ax.scatter(range(num_noise_trials), trial_slopes, marker='.', s=10, label='trial estimate')
ax.axhline(y=ref_slope, color='tab:purple', linewidth=2, label='non-noised estimate')
ax.set_ylabel('slope')
ax.set_title(
    f'slope | max={np.max(trial_slopes):.2f}, min={np.min(trial_slopes):.2f}',
    fontsize=10
)

ax = axs[1]
ax.scatter(range(num_noise_trials), trial_intercepts, marker='.', s=10)
ax.axhline(y=ref_intercept, color='tab:purple', linewidth=2)
ax.set_ylabel('intercept')
ax.set_title(
    f'intercept | max={np.max(trial_intercepts):.2f}, min={np.min(trial_intercepts):.2f}',
    fontsize=10
)

ax.set_xlabel('trial number')
f.legend(ncols=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 0.02))
f.suptitle('Parameter estimation in uniform-noise trials')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will certainly test this